# .txt file to linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am currently trying to open a .txt file, read the file line by line, and then segment by segment into a respective data type in a node.

Im having trouble with this, because every time I try to print out the list, it just prints a part of the forth entry line over and over again along with a part of the fifth entry line.

can anyone take a look at my code, and tell me what's going on? offer any insight and help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;



struct nodeinfo{
    string prob_id; 
    string idnum;
    string prob_name;
    string probname;
    string diffl;
    string diff;
    nodeinfo *next;
}; 




int main()
{
    //node ppointers
    nodeinfo * current;//nod head pointer that will point to something
    nodeinfo * head; //node current pointer that will point to a new node
    nodeinfo * temp ; //node temp pointer that will point to the same node that current is pointing too
    current = new nodeinfo;
    temp = current;
    head = current;

    

    //to bring in filename and open it
    ifstream infilename;
    infilename.open("input21.txt");
    string line;

    while (infilename)
    {
      getline(infilename, line, ':');
      infilename >> current ->prob_id;
      getline(infilename, line, ',');
      infilename>>current->idnum;
      getline(infilename, line, ':');
      infilename >> current->prob_name;
      getline(infilename, line, ',');
      infilename >> current->probname;
      getline(infilename, line, ':');
      infilename>>current->diffl;
      getline(infilename, line);
      infilename >>current->diff;
      temp -> next = current;
      temp = temp->next;
    }
    
    current->next =NULL;
   
    while (current!=NULL)
    {
        cout << current->prob_id <<current->probname<<
        current->diff<<endl;
    }

}
```

here is the input21.txt file:

1. problem_id:321038, problem_name:Binary Search Tree to Greater Sum Tree, difficulty:Medium
2. problem_id:580101, problem_name:Shortest Unsorted Continuous Subarray, difficulty:Easy
3. problem_id:297978, problem_name:Find All Numbers Disappeared in an Array, difficulty:Easy
4. problem_id:123297, problem_name:Serialize and Deserialize Binary Tree, difficulty:Hard
5. problem_id:297985, problem_name:Validate Binary Search Tree, difficulty:Medium

where each one is one line.

I want to check and see if im translating this file into a linked list and then I want to print it to be sure its there for manipulation later on.

please nothing fancy, keep things simple. thank you

Comment: You never allocate any new nodes so you only have the one node you allocate at the beginning of main

Comment: Did you manage to make a linked list with simpler data? Like ints counting up?

Comment: @AlanBirtles ah I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is simple, if you want to create a list with five items (one for each line in your file) then you need to allocate five nodes. But your code only allocates one node. You need to allocate a node each time go around your loop.

Comment: so I can't have 5 different data types in one node? and manipulate it that way? lets say I add the struct to a class? can I manipulate the data in the node with the functions in the class?

Comment: @StephanieOnyejekwe You're misusing the phrase data type. I guess you mean could you have five different problems in one node. The answer is that you could, but what if your file contained six problems? The only sensible way to handle this is to have one problem in one node, and create as many nodes as you have problems.

Comment: @StephanieOnyejekwe Putting the struct into a class serves no purpose I can see. If you want to add some functions, then just add them to the struct. Structs can have functions just like classes.